# Using javascript/jquery, how to do magnifying zoom on an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a magnifying zoom on image on mouse hover. It should look like following the image. How could I do this without using any plugins?

[image]

Comment: Check this answer out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811041/javascript-zoom-in-on-mouseover-without-jquery-or-plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it uses two different images, a small one and then a larger version of the same image for magnification.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var native_width = 0;
  var native_height = 0;
  $(".magnify").mousemove(function(e) {
    if(!native_width && !native_height) {
   var image_object = new Image();
   image_object.src = $(".small").attr("src");

   native_width = image_object.width;
   native_height = image_object.height;
    } else {
   var magnify_offset = $(this).offset();
   var mx = e.pageX - magnify_offset.left;
   var my = e.pageY - magnify_offset.top;
   
   if(mx < $(this).width() && my < $(this).height() && mx > 0 && my > 0) {
  $(".large").fadeIn(100);
   } else {
  $(".large").fadeOut(100);
   }
   if($(".large").is(":visible")) {
  var rx = Math.round(mx/$(".small").width()*native_width - $(".large").width()/2)*-1;
  var ry = Math.round(my/$(".small").height()*native_height - $(".large").height()/2)*-1;
  var bgp = rx + "px " + ry + "px";
    
  var px = mx - $(".large").width()/2;
    var py = my - $(".large").height()/2;

  $(".large").css({left: px, top: py, backgroundPosition: bgp});
   }
 }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}

.magnify {
  width: 200px; 
  margin: 50px auto; 
  position: relative;
}

.large {
  width: 175px; height: 175px;
  position: absolute;
 
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85), 
 0 0 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 
  inset 0 0 40px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 
  background: url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/iphone.jpg') no-repeat;
  display: none;
}

.small { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="magnify">
<div class="large"></div>
<img class="small" src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/iphone.jpg" width="200"/>
</div>
```

Modified from: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/magnifying-glass-for-images-using-jquery-and-css3

Comment: it is helpful. But problem is that,when the image dynamically added in image url. How i replace the css image background url?

Comment: To change it with JQuery, `$(".large").css("background-image", "url('whatever.png')");` or you could just change the css beforehand.