# How to do zoom on an image while a mouseover when HTML & CSS are in the same editor page

Tags: html, css, image, zooming, mouseover

I am working on a HTLM editor who combine HTML & CSS in the same page. I want that the users have a zoom when mouseover on a picture in front page

```html
<h4><img style="border: 1px solid black; align: right;" title="" src="sys_attachment.do?sys_id=00ee33cbdb1b9c507261e03cd396190b" alt="" width="204" align="right" border="1" hspace="" vspace="" /></h4>
<h4><strong>4. Entrez votre mot de passe.</strong></h4>
<ul style="list-style-type: disc; list-style-position: inside;">
    <li>Puis, cliquez sur "Suivant".</li>
</ul>
```

I searched for solution but the solution is always when HTML and CSS are separated
If someone has any advice or solution, please help me !

Sorry for my english, i am still learning !

Comment: I suggest reading up on CSS. Anything in a separate file can be included inline. You could also just paste the contents of that file into a <style> tag in the header. Beyond that, you shouldn't be doing all of your styling inline anyways. It's bad practice and it isn't hard at all to include an external CSS file.

Comment: btw, you can't have Hover effect without  using either `<style>` or a separated file (or JS)

Comment: you know that you can include style element into your html file where you will set all your css. If this is what you want ?

Comment: Can you add CSS Firstly in question ?

Comment: @MaxiGui This is what i want (i think !) but i don't know where i have to place it

Comment: @RayeesAC I can't add any file, sorry

Comment: try this `img:hover{transform:scale(1.5)}`

Comment: @Laif Do you have any example of that ?

Comment: What, specifically? @SRP

Comment: @Laif An example when i can paste the contents into a <style> ? I have to say i don't see the header of my page

Comment: When I say header I'm referring to the <head> tag. Refer to MaziGui's answer below, he used what I am talking about. Again, you should really be using an external CSS sheet.

Comment: Thx for your advice i will try what MaziGui said. And i will paste your message about an external CSS sheet aha !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a full example working with css `:hover`. No need JS.

You need to set the `style` element into your `head` element out of `body` element

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    .zoom {
      transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
    }

    .zoom:hover {
      transform: scale(1.5); /* (150% zoom - Note: if the zoom is too large, it will go outside of the viewport) */
      position:absolute;
      right:0;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <hr />
    <h4 class="zoom"><img style="border: 1px solid black; align: right;" title="" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/09/13/03/bike-riding-5557589_1280.png" alt="" width="204" align="right" border="1" hspace="" vspace="" /></h4>
    <h4><strong>4. Entrez votre mot de passe.</strong></h4>
    <ul style="list-style-type: disc; list-style-position: inside;">
    <li>Puis, cliquez sur "Suivant".</li>
    </ul>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a solution with JS Adapt from answer here : [Javascript: Zoom in on mouseover WITHOUT Jquery or plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811041/javascript-zoom-in-on-mouseover-without-jquery-or-plugins)

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <hr />
      <h4>
        <img id="imgZoom" style="border: 1px solid black; align: right;" width="200px" height="200px" align="right" onmousemove="zoomIn(event)" onmouseout="zoomOut()" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/09/13/03/bike-riding-5557589_1280.png">
        <div style="border: 1px solid black;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            display: none;
            background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/09/13/03/bike-riding-5557589_1280.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;"
            id="overlay"
            onmousemove="zoomIn(event)"></div>
        </h4>
      <h4><strong>4. Entrez votre mot de passe.</strong></h4>
      <ul style="list-style-type: disc; list-style-position: inside;">
      <li>Puis, cliquez sur "Suivant".</li>
      </ul>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    
    
    <script>
      function zoomIn(event) {
        var element = document.getElementById("overlay");
        element.style.display = "inline-block";
        var img = document.getElementById("imgZoom");
        var posX = event.offsetX ? (event.offsetX) : event.pageX - img.offsetLeft;
        var posY = event.offsetY ? (event.offsetY) : event.pageY - img.offsetTop;
        element.style.backgroundPosition = (-posX * 4) + "px " + (-posY * 4) + "px";

      }

      function zoomOut() {
        var element = document.getElementById("overlay");
        element.style.display = "none";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Last example with `style` directly in body:
It is accepted normaly based https://www.w3.org/Submission/1996/1/WD-jsss-960822

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <style>
      .zoom {
        transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
      }

      .zoom:hover {
        transform: scale(1.5); /* (150% zoom - Note: if the zoom is too large, it will go outside of the viewport) */
        position:absolute;
        right:0;
      }
      </style>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <hr />
    <h4 class="zoom"><img style="border: 1px solid black; align: right;" title="" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/09/13/03/bike-riding-5557589_1280.png" alt="" width="204" align="right" border="1" hspace="" vspace="" /></h4>
    <h4><strong>4. Entrez votre mot de passe.</strong></h4>
    <ul style="list-style-type: disc; list-style-position: inside;">
    <li>Puis, cliquez sur "Suivant".</li>
    </ul>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't have the header on the editor, you can check all i see here :

https://pastebin.com/FiScLYJa

Comment: `header` element and `head` are totaly different. Plus, the code you are providing goes for sur into a `body` element

Comment: This is all i can modify is it still possible to include the <style> ?

Comment: @SRP Ok in this case, you can check the 2nd snippet I added it is with js and it all goes to the body element

Comment: I added all your code since the first <p> to the last <script> and almost everything is automatically deleted, i just got this as the rest : https://pastebin.com/yn1q8u9H

I don't have the right to use JS i think

Comment: Can you tell me on what type of project you are working ? Because it might that it is deleting script element for security reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222030/discussion-between-srp-and-maxigui).