# Scale image to original size on hover

Tags: css

I have some text mixed with emoji (small images), currently I have a feature where if you mouse over those emojis they will enlarge in-place, this is done using the following css

```
.emoji:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}
.emoji {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```

I want to have the emojis scale to their original size, rather than to a fixed amount, kinda like the following

```
.emoji:hover {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
.emoji {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```

Yet this have the undesirable side-effect of re-flowing the text which `transform: scale(2)` doesn't have. Is there some way around it?

a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/05eanuf4/

Comment: Could you not find out the original dimensions and set it to that?

Comment: One option is to scale it down originally: `scale(0.5)` and then scale it normally on hover: `scale(1)`

Comment: First [determine original size of the image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1944298/7994967), then dynamically scale the image with javascript: `element.style.transform = "scale("+ originalWidth / 32 +")";`

Comment: So this is impossible to do with only css? I'm not very familiar with javascript, but I'd imagine I wound need to attach some event to every emoji? and since they are generated dynamically I would need to loop over all the emojis regularly in case some was newly created?

Comment: i hope this site help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale#:~:text=The%20scale()%20CSS%20function,transform%2Dfunction%3E%20data%20type.

Comment: I thought about setting the margin to a negative number size down the element, but percentage margin 100% is relative to it's parent's width, not the element itself. it seems all road leads to doom :(

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution only with CSS.

### DEMO hover emoji 2:

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}

.emoji, .emoji2 {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.emoji:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}

.emoji2:hover{
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  /*max-height:100vh; /* LIMIT THE HEIGHT to the height of the screen */
  /*max-width: 100vw; /* LIMIT THE WIDTH to the width of the screen */
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/322/indian-heads-1391201.jpg" alt="image" class="emoji" />
<br>
<br>
<h2> Hover to normal size</h2>
<img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/322/indian-heads-1391201.jpg" alt="image" class="emoji2" />
```

You can also check this subject: [How to do "zoom on an image while a mouseover" when html & css are in the same editor page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049671/how-to-do-zoom-on-an-image-while-a-mouseover-when-html-css-are-in-the-same-e/64049817#64049817)

### DEMO 2 (based on code given):

```css
.emoji {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
span{
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
span:hover{
  background: url(https://wm.sdf.org/gallery/albums/userpics/10644/alice.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  top: 12px;
  margin-top:-12px;
}
span:hover .emoji {
  /*transform: scale(2);*/
  position:absolute;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  top: 32px;
}
```

```html
text above text above text above text above
<br>
text in front <span><img src="https://wm.sdf.org/gallery/albums/userpics/10644/alice.png" alt=":alice:" title=":alice:" class="emoji"></span> <span><img src="https://wm.sdf.org/gallery/albums/userpics/10644/alice.png" alt=":alice:" title=":alice:" class="emoji"></span> <span><img src="https://wm.sdf.org/gallery/albums/userpics/10644/alice.png" alt=":alice:" title=":alice:" class="emoji"></span> some text behind
<br>
text below text below text below text below
```

You can also check this subject: [How to do "zoom on an image while a mouseover" when html & css are in the same editor page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049671/how-to-do-zoom-on-an-image-while-a-mouseover-when-html-css-are-in-the-same-e/64049817#64049817)

### DEMO 3 (based on code given):

```css
span{
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.background{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.emoji {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  display:none;
}
span .background:hover + .emoji {
  /*transform: scale(2);*/
  position:absolute;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  top: 32px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
text above text above text above text above
<br>
text in front <span>
<img src="https://wm.sdf.org/gallery/albums/userpics/10644/alice.png" alt=":alice:" title=":alice:" class="background">
<img src="https://wm.sdf.org/gallery/albums/userpics/10644/alice.png" alt=":alice:" title=":alice:" class="emoji"></span> <span><img src="https://wm.sdf.org/gallery/albums/userpics/10644/alice.png" alt=":alice:" title=":alice:" class="background"><img src="https://wm.sdf.org/gallery/albums/userpics/10644/alice.png" alt=":alice:" title=":alice:" class="emoji"></span> <span><img src="https://wm.sdf.org/gallery/albums/userpics/10644/alice.png" alt=":alice:" title=":alice:" class="background"><img src="https://wm.sdf.org/gallery/albums/userpics/10644/alice.png" alt=":alice:" title=":alice:" class="emoji"></span> some text behind
<br>
text below text below text below text below
```

Comment: This is almost working, the problem is upon hover the image lost it's original place. it leads to problems when there's mutiple image in a row, where the other image will just flow together.

Comment: @tleydxdy Have a look to the new demo I updated based on your code.

Comment: @tleydxdy check demo 3, it will work with any pricture no matter what.

Comment: yeah, it seems like the only way to make it work is to tweak the html :(

Comment: Yeah after you might try to use `mouseover` in js. that could help you. Here I really tried to stay with pure css

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique class name that can be used across other images you'd want to scale on your project... I'm using "scale" as my unique class name, and then add styles:

.scale {transition: all .2s ease-in-out;}

.scale:hover {transform: scale(1.01);}

Comment: When answering an HTML/CSS question it's often helpful to add a snippet to your answer, which can be rendered inside the page and your code's effects can be seen clearly.